# recordtypeid web2lead form not saving correct

Tags: record-type, html, leads, web2lead

I have the following web2lead form where I add a recordtype. On submit it still generates a default lead recordtype. Am I missing something?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="recordType" id="recordType" value="0121t000000Qf3qAAC">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://www.xxxxxxx.com/">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>
Message:<textarea  id="00N1t00000K2v9Q" name="00N1t00000K2v9Q" rows="5" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you verified the profile of the default creator for Web-to-Lead settings to see if the profile has access to the record type mentioned as in the form or not?

Comment: @JayantDas I did this is a system admin profile

Comment: So does the system admin profile has the record type assigned?

Comment: @JayantDas The profile has all the recordtypes assigned but there is 1 default recordtype. On creating a new lead I can select all recordtypes

Comment: Well not quite sure then, you may like to verify if there are any triggers/workflow updates, etc. on the Lead record which could be possibly changing the record type.

Comment: @JayantDas I am shure there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all who bump into this issue. I had the recordtype assigned to the profile. Another step that needs to be done is on the Lead setting put this setting on:

- Keep the existing record type